# How to count overlapped strings within another string?

Tags: python, string

If I have a string `str1=boobbobobpzfsbobboobbobb` and I want to count how many times the string `'bob'` is present inside it. However, I cannot use `str1.count` as it only counts non overlapped strings. SO what do I do?

Answer (score 2):

Using [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re) (positive lookahead assertion):

```
>>> import re
>>> str1 = 'boobbobobpzfsbobboobbobb'
>>> sum(1 for m in re.finditer('b(?=ob)', str1))
4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it in quadratic time (worst case) by considering all the substrings starting at an increasing index and counting how many start with `"bob"`:

```
str1 = "boobbobobpzfsbobboobbobb"

times = 0   
for pos in range(len(str1)):
    if str1[pos:].startswith("bob"):
        times += 1

print(times)
```

or:

```
str1  = "boobbobobpzfsbobboobbobb"

times = sum(1 for x in range(len(str1)) if str1[x:].startswith("bob"))

print(times)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

str1 = 'boobbobobpzfsbobboobbobb'

len(re.findall('b(?=ob)',str1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little one-liner for it:

```
str1 = "boobbobobpzfsbobboobbobb"
str2 = 'bob'

count = sum([str1[k:k+len(str2)]==str2 for k in range(0, len(str1)-len(str2)+1)])

# OUTPUT: 4
```